# Line Items module?

Tags: entities

What options do I have in implementing line items, other than using an extra content type for each type of line item?

Line items, can be more purchase order order items, addresses, etc.

Seems to me, it would be a common requirement to have something which is query-able by VIEWS but not it's own content-type, but configurable through an UI?!?

I thought entities were designed to address this issue but I don't see any easy UI to allow creation/updating/associating sub-entities (for lack of better term)

When I google for a module like this I only seem to find Commerce modules -- not exactly what I was hoping for.

Any ideas???

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Any reason not to use D7 Commerce?

Comment: Could you please make your title more specific? I was sure you are talking about something in existing commerce modules.

Comment: How about using the "Message" module, to create 1 message (which are entities ... and configurable!) for each line item? And this by using Rules, which creates such "messages" somewhere around the time of checkout or something? To better understand what I mean, have a look at my answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137960/how-to-log-and-display-all-the-users-that-have-edited-a-node-without-revisionin/227893#227893) ...

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Construction Kit](http://drupal.org/project/eck) provides a decent UI for managing entities, and integrates with Views nicely.

Comment: I've seen the ECK but will that allow me to build something like line items? They are not commerce related so I wasn't sure if they would work. A generic line item module would be best that was configurable, I don't want the line items implemented a content types but perhaps as entities.