# How to track an action when user creates a node of a specific content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, users, social-network

I use Drupal 7 and I want to track an action when user creates a node of a specific content type.

I installed the [Facebook Pixel](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_pixel) and [Facebook Tracking Pixel](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_tracking_pixel) modules, but they don't support my needs. Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, which allows for dozens of variations of tracking. As an example, here is a prototype of a rule, in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format, to illustrate the possibilities:

```
{ "rules_find_links_in_body" : {
    "LABEL" : "Find links in body",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      },
      { "OR" : [
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "node:body:value" ],
              "match" : "http(|s):\/\/+",
              "operation" : "regex"
            }
          },
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "node:body:value" ],
              "match" : "ANotAllowedTextStringInBody",
              "operation" : "regex"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Node body contains an URL ..." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about the above prototype rule:

- **Rules Event** = After saving new content of type "Article" (adapt the type to fit your needs).
- **Rules Conditions**:

  - Check if the current user is an authenticated user.
  - Perform a text comparison, using a **Regular Expression** as the **Comparison operation** (which you can perfectly do in Rules, without using the PHP filter for it). For the actual regular expression, this rule uses `http(|s)://+`, which will discover strings that start with either `http://` or `https://`. Should you have additional / similar requirements to discover variations of this (say some other string like `ANotAllowedTextStringInBody`), another Rules Condition (with an *OR*) will take care of that also.
- **Rules Action** = Show a message on the site (adapt the message to fit your needs), and/or add other relevant Rules Actions ... Such as:

  - use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module as illustrated in [the answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/227893/39516) to "[How to log and display all the users that have edited a node (without revisioning)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/137960/39516)".
  - send an eMail, either to a specific user, or all users of a specific role.
  - use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to flag the user (for whatever reason).
  - grant a special role to the user.
  - ... (the possibilities are only limited by your own imagination).

**Voilà**, easy as that ...